# Javascript variable becomes undefined when passed as an argument to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular program with a service which holds a map of current value (very much like a context). At different places in my program I call that service to get the currentValue of something. The service is called CrsViewContext and the methods are quite simple

```
.service('CrsViewContext', function () {
    var currentInstances = {};

    this.setCurrent = function (domain, instance) {
        currentInstances[domain] = instance;
        console.log('ViewContext setCurrent: ' + domain);
        console.dir(instance);
    };

    this.getCurrent = function (domain) {
        console.log('ViewContext getCurrent: ' + domain);
        console.dir(currentInstances[domain]);
        return currentInstances[domain];
    };

    this.resetCurrent = function (domain) {
        console.log('ViewContext resetCurrent: ' + domain);
        currentInstances[domain] = null;
    };
});
```

In my controller I pass this CrsViewContext as an argument and do something like that

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function (CrsViewContext) {
   var n = CrsViewContext.getCurrent ('RealEstate');
   console.log ("get current Real estate");
   console.dir (n);
   console.log ("current real estate id: "+n.id);
 });
```

However the last log gets undefined even though that in my console I can see the prior statement returning an object that defines an id and its value

Something to do with Javascript and/or Restangular since I use Restangular to retrieve that object. Also on an side note if you access it from the console, you have no problem getting the id

```
   n=$('#wrapper').injector().get('CrsViewContext').getCurrent('RealEstate').id;
```

returns 3 from the console

Thanks in advance

Pascal

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but it is kind of a code smell that "currentInstances" is global. Why not replace "currentInstances" with "this.currentInstances" and initialize it in the constructor of your controller object?

Comment: It is not global. It is defined inside a service which is a Singleton. My understanding is that it won't be reachable from outside the service as opposed to variables or functions added to this

Comment: ah, it wasn't clear from the snippet that there is a function surrounding the code excerpt.

Comment: Thanks Michaels. I modified the code to include the service and controller definition. I have a feeling it has to do with Restangular that returns promises and that possibly console.dir treat a promise differently (wait for its completion) than the javascript code.

Comment: @PascalDeMilly: It's not clear what `instance` looks like (so I cant propose a proper solution), but indeed it is a common issue that `console.log` will output an object as it is at the time of printing and not as it is at the time of calling `console.log` (and although not apparent, the actual printing happens a little later). In such cases it is better to construct your layout so that as soon as the value is available, it will update the view (or whatever). Giving more context on what are you trying to achieve, would help...

Answer (score 0):

After much poking I removed a call to $object that was made on the variable earlier in the code. Restanglar returns promises and it was my understanding that calling $object on a promise will guarantee its value returned but it is not. Keeping those variables as promises seems to work. Don't really understand why –